# Relationships of a child entity of ManagedObject gives wrong object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

To reduce redundant data I have made a parent entity of User. Both patient and Midwife are children of User.

The only additional data is that a Midwife has a set of patients and a Patient can have a set of midwifes.

[image: Screenshot of the managed object when importing]

When I am populating the managed objects to core data it shows that their relationships to the correct objects.

[image: Screenshot of Core Data Model]

The problem is, when I try to retrieve the object using the User class the relationship of the ManagedObject is pointing to the wrong object (it actually points to the same ManagedObject).

I query core data using the predicate `NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username == '%@' AND password == '%@'", username, password];`

When I attempt to login using my helper method I check to see if the object is a Midwife or a Patient so I know what relationship to call. But the relationship is pointing to the wrong object.

```
[User userWithUsername:username
              password:password
               success:^(id user) {                
                   if([user isKindOfClass:[Midwife class]])
                   {
                       NSLog(@"Midwife : %@", [user fullName]);
                       dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"midwifeDashboard" sender:self];
                       });
                   }
                   else if([user isKindOfClass:[Patient class]])
                   {
                       NSLog(@"Patient : %@", [user fullName]);
                       dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"patientDashboard" sender:self];
                       });
                   }
               }
               failure:^(NSError *error) {
                   NSLog(@"Error %@", [error description]);
                   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Invalid username or password"];
                   });
               }];
```

It knows what class the object is and calls the correct segue but this is where my data and their relationships become corrupt.

I assume it is because I am casting a Midwife Managed Object to a User Managed Object but how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I perform the fetch request like so

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[[MDCDataStore sharedInstance] store] newPrivateContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];

[context performBlock:^{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
}];
```

Could it be the entityDescription messing this up?

Comment: Where is it that you try to access the relationship?  You say that isKindOfClass is working for you, and you say that somewhere you're casting to User* -- but I don't see that.

Comment: @stevesliva sorry for the late reply. In the userWithUsername method I query the User class with the predicate shown in the question. I don't cast it to a User, it is passed back as an id. Only once I perform the isKindOfClass do I then cast it to what ever class it is so I can call the correct methods on it. Even if I don't cast it and use the user object with type id the relationship is still wrong.

Comment: Just trying to see at which point things go wrong.   If the object respondsToSelector for the relationship, and isKindOfClass of the right subclass, it's hard to see anything wrong with the code you have here.  Of course you can call superclass methods.   Are you casting `self` to a subclass in a User class method?  Which is not necessarily a problem, it's just that it might be *there* because I don't see it here...

Comment: @stevesliva I have updated the question to include the part where I query core data.

Comment: What is going wrong, though? You say "but this is where my data and their relationships become corrupt." Can you be more specific about what is corrupted? How is the user being passed to the segue? Are you sharing an `NSManagedObject` across multiple threads?

Comment: @IanHenry @stevesliva The problem is when I am importing my data, all is well. The relationship from Patient to midwifes shows what I expect. (Seen in the log print out image.) Strangely when I come to retrieve that managed object using a private context the relationship becomes corrupt. So if I went `[_patient midwifes]` it would return the Patient managed object that I am calling from not the set of Midwifes for that patient. The import is done on a private context and then merged once the import is done.

Comment: In that new block... why create fetchedObjects in a block?  fetchedObjects scope then just disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was no problem. It was only that when I NSLog the user.patients property it is faulted. If I enumerate through them I get the correct and entire object.

Thanks everyone for your help.