# NSManagedObjectContext is fine at first but then when accessed later it is nil

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two NSManageObjects, `Midwife` and `Patient`. These both have the parent entity of `User`. The only difference is that a `Midwife` object has a many to many relationship to `Patient` and the `Patient` object has a many to many relationship to `Midwife`

[image: This shows the NSManagedObjects and their relationships]

When I get the active user it correctly returns the user and identifies if it is a `Midwife` or a `Patient`. You can see with the image below that it correctly retrieves the object I want with the patients relationship faulted.
[image]

Using the code below I determine that the relationship is a fault then try to access a property to make core data fulfil the fault. I then add the object to a mutable array to be used late in a collection view.

```
[User activeUserSuccess:^(id user) {
    self.activeMidwife = (Midwife *)user;
    self.patients = [@[] mutableCopy];

    [[[_activeMidwife patients] allObjects] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Patient *patient, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Is fault : %i", [patient isFault]);
        [patient fullName];
        NSLog(@"Is fault : %i", [patient isFault]);

        [_patients addObject:patient];
    }];

} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error : %@", [error description]);
}];
```

The first `NSLog` returns `"Is fault : 1"` and then once I call the `fullName` method (this simply places the forename and surname property together with a space) the object is then loaded and the second NSLog outputs `"Is fault : 0"` Whilst still in the enumerate block I print out the `patient.mangaedObjectContext` and here it returns a valid `managedObjectContext` it then adds it to the mutable array and does this fall all patents for the active midwife.

The problem is when I access the `_patents` array from within the `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method the managedObjectContext is nil. My code is below.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MDCCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Patient *patient = _patients[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Is fault : %i", [patient isFault]);
    NSLog(@"Patitne name %@", patient.forename);
    NSLog(@"Is fault : %i", [patient isFault]);
    [[cell patientNameLabel] setText:[patient fullName]];

    return cell;
}
```

Within these two `NSLog`s they both output `"Is fault : 1"`. When debuting I found that the patent object at this point the `patent` object has a nil `managedObjectContext`. Would anyone know why or accord this problem before.

My `persistentStore` is only `init` once and accessed via a `sharedInstance`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where does the managedObjectContext live in your program? When you say you have one location where the MOC is valid, and another where it's not... it's relevant to know whether that first location is a view controller or delegate or whatever that's gone out of scope and been deallocated.  And if so, whether you saved changes to that MOC, or merged them, or whatever.

Comment: When I perform a fetch request make a new private context by calling `NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[[MDCDataStore sharedInstance] store] newPrivateContext];` It then performs that fetch request and I get back to objects. In the MDCDataStore is where I hold my persistent store.

Comment: What I need to do is have an array of all the `Patents` for the `Midwife` and have access to their data.

Comment: So after you perform the fetch, the MOC just goes out of scope.   What if the managedObjectContext pointer in you Patient object is a weak reference?  Well, the managedObjectContext it was pointing to becomes nil...  And it's probably a weak reference by design.  You're supposed to keep the MOC, not the objects.

Comment: Ahhh, well shouldn't this happen because I make a new private context to perform the fetch request. Once I have them objects and the request has been excited then it will dealloc the new private context. I'm not sure if the MOC being nil is the problem, it is just what I noticed when accessing it within the collection view data source method.

Comment: This is a question I posted to give more detail about the what I am trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993233/relationships-of-a-child-entity-of-managedobject-gives-wrong-object

Comment: My point is that it sounds like it makes sense that the pointer in the object to the MOC is nil-- because the MOC is gone. Retain count zero, deallocated.  Doesn't that address the title of your question post?  If that's an issue, keep a strong reference to the MOC somewhere.

Comment: Yes, if you post it as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer. What I don't know is because there is no link back to the store it can no longer fulfil the fault because it has not MOC to ask. How can I do this?

Comment: That's why I didn't "answer" per se.  I have zero idea what is supposed to happen when you keep pointers to entity instances but not the context.  It's possible you're supposed to be able to access attributes but not relationships.  I dunno.

Comment: "I then add the object to a mutable array to be used late in a collection view." Why aren't you using a fetched results controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer to reflect comments.  If the MOC goes out of scope, then it makes sense the entity instance pointers that you've retained have internal pointers to a MOC that's now nil.

Beyond that, I don't know what is supposed to happen with the usability or mutability of these NSManagedObjects that are now retained outside the scope of the MOC you got them from.  So there's potentially a more informed answer about what you could or could not do with that array you've created.

Comment: I have fixed the problem but I am not too sure if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off refactoring your design to have the MDCDataStore perform all the fetches and just return Arrays of Patients per each MidWife.

Comment: But surly the idea of relationships is so I can go from one ManagedObject to another without having to make or use another method?

Comment: Yes I agree- you will stil use the relationship created for your Core Data model but when you're having trouble with maintaining a reference to your ManagedObjectContext it might be easier for you to have all the Data Model methods organized together in one class.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working. I had to return the managed objects that were on the main context.

By adding the code below to get the objects on the `mainContext` this worked.

```
[fetchedObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    id entity = [[[MDCDataStore sharedInstance] mainContext] objectWithID:[obj objectID]];
    [objectsOnMainContxt addObject:entity];
}];
```

Is there a better way to do this?

The entire function is as below

```
+ (void)entityName:(NSString *)entityName predicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:(NSArray *)relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching success:(void (^)(NSArray *fetchedObjects))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[[MDCDataStore sharedInstance] store] newPrivateContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [context performBlock:^{
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        [fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching];
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

        NSMutableArray *objectsOnMainContxt = [@[] mutableCopy];

        if([fetchedObjects count] > 0)
        {
            [fetchedObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                id entity = [[[MDCDataStore sharedInstance] mainContext] objectWithID:[obj objectID]];
                [objectsOnMainContxt addObject:entity];
            }];

            if(success)
            {
                success(objectsOnMainContxt);
            }
        }
        else if(failure)
        {
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithCode:CoreDataErrorCodeEntityNotFound
                                         reason: @"There were no managed objects that matched the predicate and that existed in the context."
                                    description:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No managed object matched the predicate '%@'.", [predicate predicateFormat]]
                                     suggestion:@"Ensure you are passing in the correct params into the predicate."];

            failure(error);
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: "Main context"? Are you using thread confinement or queue confinement?